# Inconsistent definition of a vector in differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, riemannian-geometry

In the context of studying general relativity, I've seen two different definitions of a vector that seem inconsistent with one another.

The first says in some coordinate basis on a Riemannian manifold, a vector field is a derivation

$$V = V^\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta}$$

using the Einstein summation convention. It is a mapping $V:C^\infty \rightarrow C^\infty$. For some smooth scalar field $\phi \in C^\infty$ we have

$$V(\phi) = V^\beta\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^\beta}$$

The second definition says a vector field is a ${1 \choose 0}$  tensor field. It operates on a one-form field $p$ to give a scalar field. In a coordinate basis

$$V(p) = V(p_\alpha \omega^\alpha) = p_\alpha V(\omega^\alpha) = p_\alpha V^\alpha \in C^\infty$$

where $\omega^\alpha$ are the basis one-forms and $p^\alpha$ are the components of the one-form field (they are scalar fields themselves).

In the second definition, as opposed to the first, we can pull the scalar field $p_\alpha$ out of the vector. How can these two definitions be consistent or even describe the same geometric object?

Comment: If you want to use local coordinates, much more is needed to be said in both definitions. But, a vector field as a derivation on functions (no coordinates are needed) is the standard definition. If you define tensor fields correctly, this is the same as a $(1,0)$-tensor. The equivalence of the two definitions (the standard and the 2nd definition you gave) is a theorem, which essentially amounts to saying that for a finite-dimensional (real) vector space $W$, $(W^*)^*\cong W$. Incidentally, in the 2nd definition, how did they define differential forms without defining vector fields first?

Comment: Thank you! In the 2nd "definition" I found, it was more of a retroactive labeling of a vector field rather than a definition.

Comment: Your second definition of a vector field cannot be a definition because to define what a tensor is you need to know about tangent vectors and fields.

Comment: indeed in almost any physics textbook almost everything is inconsistent from a serious mathematical point of view, not just the book you are reading now.

Comment: It is known that if we know that $b_i$ generate a vector space $E$ then this generate a linear $E^*\to\mathbb R$ via $$b_i(f)=f(b_i),$$ for each linear $f:E\to\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $V$ induce a $p\mapsto V(p)$ from 1-form to a $C^{\infty}$ is because if you chose $p=p_{\alpha}\omega^{\alpha}$ and operate
\begin{eqnarray*}
V(p)&=&p(V)\\ 
&=&p_{\alpha}\omega^{\alpha}\left(V^{\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial^{\mu}}
\right)\\
&=&p_{\alpha}V^{\mu}\omega^{\alpha}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}
\right),\end{eqnarray*}
for each dual basis $\omega^{\sigma}$,
where, upon choosing these as the coordinated ones $w^{\alpha}=dx^{\alpha}$ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
V(p)&=&
p_{\alpha}V^{\mu}\omega^{\alpha}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}\right)\\
\\
&=&p_{\alpha}V^{\mu}dx^{\alpha}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}\right)\\
\\
&=&p_{\alpha}V^{\mu}\delta^{\alpha}_{\mu}\\
\\
&=&p_{\alpha}V^{\alpha}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

The second definition is really a definition of a $1$-form and not a vector.

You first define a tangent vector (i.e., $(1,0)$-tensor) at a point $p$ to be a derivation $V_p: C^\infty \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that if $f \in C^\infty$ has a critical point at $p$, then $V_p(f) = 0$. The set of all tangent vectors at $p$ is a vector space called the tangent space at $p$ and usually denoted $T_p$.

The dual vector space $T^*_p$ is called the cotangent space at $p$ and any element $\theta \in T_P^*$ is called a $1$-form, covector, or $(0,1)$-tensor. By definition, any element $\theta \in T^*_p$ is a linear function of $V \in T_p$. If $(\partial_1, \dots, \partial_n)$ is a basis of $T_p$ and $(\omega^1, \dots, \omega^n)$ is the corresponding dual basis, then given any $V = V^\alpha\partial_\alpha \in T_p$ and $1$-form $b = b_\alpha\omega^\alpha$, then by the definition of a dual basis,
$$
b(V) = = b_\alpha V^\alpha.
$$